# Increase Vertical Spacing between shapes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to increase the spacing between two shapes in PowerPoint.

On every run, the vertical space between the shapes needs to increase. I am unable to do that.

```vb
Sub Increase_Vertical_Spacing2()

    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim Height_Shp As Double
    Dim Top_Shp As Double
    Dim left_Shp As Double
    Dim Space_Shp As Double
    Dim Space_incremental As Double
    
    Space_incremental = 5 + 1
    Dim i As Long
    
    If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionShapes Then
        i = 1
        
        For Each Shp In ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
            If i > 1 Then
                Space_Shp = Space_Shp - Shp.Top
                If Space_Shp > 0 Then
                    Space_Shp = 5
                    Shp.Top = Top_Shp + Height_Shp + Space_Shp
                Else
                    Space_Shp = Space_Shp - Space_Shp + 5
                    Shp.Top = Top_Shp + Height_Shp + Space_Shp
                End If
                
            End If
            Top_Shp = Shp.Top
            Height_Shp = Shp.Height
            Space_Shp = Top_Shp + Height_Shp
            i = i + 1
        Next Shp
    Else
        MsgBox "There is no shape currently selected!", vbExclamation, "No Shape Found"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Increase the space by the lower shape moving down or the upper shape moving up? What if the shapes are beside each other?

Answer (score 0):

@John Korchok is right with his questions -- a bit unclear. If you want to just increase vertical as your initital code is attempting to, you can have it much less complicated:

```
Sub IncreaseSpace()
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim iScount As Integer
Dim Distance As Integer


Distance = InputBox("How big is the distance you want", "Distance", 5)
iScount = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count

For iScount = 2 To ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(iScount)
.Top = .Top + ((iScount - 1) * Distance)
End With
Next iScount
End Sub
```

Comment: @Emran what is your status here?

Comment: I have used the userform to build this.